# SML/NJ - the "fun act(f,x) = f(x) ;" signature

Tags: functional-programming, smlnj

Declare on the follow function  -

```
fun act(f,x) = f(x);
```

Makes the signature  -

```
val act = fn : ('a -> 'b) * 'a -> 'b
```

What does `('a -> 'b) * 'a -> 'b` means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `act` is a function that takes a pair (2-tuple)

```
('a -> 'b) * 'a
```

where the first element is a function from `'a` to `'b`, and the second is a thing of type `'a`.
It returns a thing of type `'b`.